Always Receiving email ITMS-91061: Missing privacy manifest
I always receiving this email by apple, that my submitted app is missing privacy manifest. I am using flutter (sdk version 3.16.8). This is what i've done:

add privacy manifest file using xcode
Manually add privacy manifest
upgrade xcode to the newest version
build using real device

but nothing changes, apple still sending me the email. My full email is like:
Although submission for App Store review was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next submission for App Store review. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
ITMS-91061: Missing privacy manifest - Your app includes “Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter”, which includes Flutter, an SDK that was identified in the documentation as a privacy-impacting third-party SDK. Starting November 12, 2024, if a new app includes a privacy-impacting SDK, or an app update adds a new privacy-impacting SDK, the SDK must include a privacy manifest file. Please contact the provider of the SDK that includes this file to get an updated SDK version with a privacy manifest. For more details about this policy, including a list of SDKs that are required to include signatures and manifests
Thank you if someone can help me. I'll appreciate that.

You need to update your Flutter version to at least 3.24.0, to have PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy

Uh thank you, i'll give it a try

You need a privacy manifest in your app and in the included libs, see https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-flutter-package-privacy-manifest-compatible/
